# Does Delegate.BeginInvoke require MemoryBarrier?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, begininvoke

```
private class ParamDatas
{
    public object Param1;
    public object Param2;
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action<ParamDatas> action = ThreadAction;
    var myParamDatas = new ParamDatas();
    var result = action.BeginInvoke(myParamDatas, null, null);

    // dosomething ...
}

private static void ThreadAction(ParamDatas paramDatas)
{
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();

    // use paramDatas ....
    // var param1 = paramDatas.Param1;
}
```

Is the MemoryBarrier required in this code? 
or BeginInvoke function will avoid dirty data?

Answer (score 0):

At the time that you call `BeginInvoke` you're taking a copy of `myParamDatas` and sending a copy of that data to the function invocation.  You don't need any memory barrier or synchronization mechanism for that value to be properly provided.  Likewise, any mutations to the variable, or its value, before that function call need to be performed before the value is read, as the reading of the value at that point is on the same thread as those changes, and so need to be observed to happen in order.  This means if you set any values to that object before calling `BeginInvoke` those values will be observable in the invoked function.

If you're making any changes to the referenced object *after* calling `BeginInvoke` (on the calling thread) then you'll need an appropriate synchronization mechanism to ensure that those changes are properly synchronized with the usage of the object from the other thread.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, usage of the MemoryBarrier is required (Or Monitor/Lock). You will have to provide your own thread-safety guarantee with the use of a synchronization mechanism.

Invoking a delegate is thread safe because it's immutable but execution of the method referenced by the delegate is not thread safe.

Quoted directly from the article [MulticastDelegate Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.aspx) regarding thread safety: "Any public static ( Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. **Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.**

I hope this helps you!